# how to align content of a <div> so that they are vertically

Tags: html

Is it possible to have the content of a div vertically centred?

```
<div style="padding-left: 15px; vertical-align: middle; align-content: center" >
      <h3>Selections</h3>
</div>
```

I want the text left aligned and in the vertical middle

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I vertically align text in a div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2939914/how-do-i-vertically-align-text-in-a-div)

Comment: Brilliant! That's fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

I gave you an example of vertical alignment using `flex` rules. In this case, the vertical alignment occurs with the help of an `align-item: center`. Also, you need space for vertical alignment.

```css
body {
   padding: 0;
   margin: 0;
   box-sizing: border-box;
}

div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<div>
   <h3>Selections</h3>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well it's an easy property you can set. You can set the `text-align` property. You can read more about this below.

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_text-align.ASP

for vertical centering:

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_align.asp

Comment: Your link explains horizontal alignment.   I want vertical alignment

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the CSS property [text-align](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-align). Also remove the inline 'style' you have on your div and use a css file

```css
.center-content {
     text-align: center;
     width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="center-content">
     hello world
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are oke with setting the height of the h3 tag, you can do this:

```
h3{
  height: 4%;
  margin-top: 48%;
  margin-bottom: 48%;
}
```

Otherwise do this;

```
h3{
  margin-top: 50%;
  margin-bottom: 50%;
}
```